# can't find layout and classes in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I'm a noob in Android studio and Java, I do have a solid c# background, but I can't seem to fix this problem:

Some of my partners asked to add a button to a previous android build created by someone else, so I downloaded Android studio and imported the project, but I can't seem to find anything in there. We can't contact the creater of the project to ask in what he developed the app.

[image]

As you can see, there's no layout in the project.
And this is what the project folder looks like:
[image]

Where Can I edit layouts? Am I in the wrong IDE?

Thanks

Comment: Based on the project files it looks like the project uses cocos2dx. I'm not sure if this type of project structure will work with Android Studio, you may want to have a look at this http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_Build_an_Android_Project_with_Eclipse

Comment: Based on my previous comment you should be able to find the files you need in the `proj.android` folder.

Comment: Hey Joel, thanks for pointing out that it's made in cocos2D, I'm installing it right now, hope I can add a button then!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the Layout, you can do Two things:

OPTION 1
1. Simply click into your Xml file and select the "Text" option at the bottom on your screen

[image]

2.Change to layout

[image]

OPTION 2

1.Just drag another layout in Design and put your items in it, delete your old layout PS. you can have layouts in other layouts

[image]

[image]

Now, Thats just for the Layouts, to see classes just do...

[image]

after double clicking that, itl bring up a new tab.

[image]

PS This is somewhat a Duplicate, try to search up your question first instead of making a new question

link to duplicate: [Android Studio - How to change layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28993546/android-studio-how-to-change-layout/29661339#29661339)